# Integration of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Why don't we just integrate differential equation of f(x,y) with respect to x to get the general solution but instead we integrate part of the differential equation with respect to x and the other part with respect to y?

Consider the differential equation

```
 f'(x)=x^2
```

Y don't we integrate like this to get the answer
    $f'(x)dx=$x^2dx

Comment: How would you do it with something like this?$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$$

Answer (score 5):

If we have a differential equation like:

$$
y' = x^2y
$$

then what I understand you to be asking is: why don't we simply integrate both sides right away? It does look like this would give us $y$ on the left-hand side.

You have to remember that $y$ is a function of $x$, so we really should write it $y(x)$.

$$
y'(x) = x^2 y(x)
$$

The answer is that we have *no idea* how to do the integral

$$
\int x^2 y(x)\,dx
$$

because $y(x)$ is the function we're trying to find by solving the differential equation, and we don't know how to integrate function $y(x)$ multiplied by some $f(x)$ (in this case $f(x) = x^2$). The answer totally depends on what $y(x)$ is.

We need to split the equation apart:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2y \implies \frac{1}{y}\,dy = x^2\,dx
$$

so we can do the integration with $y$ safely isolated.